# React Router Conditional Rendering of NavBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, navbar

I've a navbar that i want to hide when the user is logged in.I don't want to display the NavBar when the user is at the '/auth' endpoint. I tried a conditional rendering but it doesn't work.

Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route ,Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Login} from './Login';
import {SignUp} from './SignUp'
import { Home } from './Home';
import Freecomponent from './Freecomponent';
import AuthComponent from './AuthComponent';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

function App() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    
return (
    <Router>
    {window.location.href === '/auth' ? null :  <Navbar />}
    <Routes>
    
        <Route path='/' element={<div><Home /></div>} exact />
        <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path='/signin' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/free' element={<Freecomponent />} />
        <Route path='/auth' element={cookies.get("TOKEN") ? <AuthComponent /> : <Navigate to='/' />} />
        
    </Routes>
    </Router>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you fix the title or the text? When do you want to display the NavBar exactly? Also: post code, not images of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React components are rendered whenever their props, state or context change. In your case `window.location.href` is none of the above. So when URL changes, React will not rerender `App` component.

1. You may use `useLocation` hook which will cause a rerender when the location changes. `useLocation` hook must be used inside of `Router` component, So you should rearrange your components in a way that `Navbar` component is rendered when user is inside `Router` component.
2. Store the status of the user(whether or not they are logged in or not, their JWT, etc in a state) which make React to rerender `App` component. You can use either state or context for that.

**Edit:**

```
function App() {
  // isLoggedIn should be read from state, props or context to make React to rerender this component
  const isLoggedIn = ...

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Routes>// Whatever you want to render when user is logged in</Routes>
    );
  }

  return <Routes>// Whatever you want to render when user is not logged in</Routes>;
}
```

Also as far as I remember, you can only render `Route` component inside `Routes`. There could be some workarounds but they are not needed.

Comment: Can't it be done by restructuring the router ?

Comment: Whatever you approach you choose, React rerenders your components only when their state, props or their context changes. Changing properties from javascript objects, like `window` will not rerender your components. Also as I mentioned you probably should not render any component rather that `Router` inside `Routes`. If you search goolge you will find different possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution i came up with , i used Outlet from react-router-dom.

Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route ,Navigate,Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Login} from './Login';
import {SignUp} from './SignUp'
import { Home } from './Home';
import Freecomponent from './Freecomponent';
import AuthComponent from './AuthComponent';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

function App() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    
return (
    <Router>
    <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<div><Home /></div>} exact />
        <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path='/signin' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/free' element={<Freecomponent />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/auth' element={cookies.get("TOKEN") ? <AuthComponent /> : <Navigate to='/' />} /> 
    </Routes>
    </Router>
);
}
 function Layout () {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
              
              <Outlet />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```